# Socket SO_SNDTIMEO Timout is double the set value

Tags: sockets, timeout, gstreamer

I recently patched my copy of GStreamer 0.10.36 to time out the tcpclientsink if the network connection is switched between wired/wireless (More information at [Method to Cancel/Abort GStreamer tcpclientsink Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548804/method-to-cancel-abort-gstreamer-tcpclientsink-timeout)).  It's a simple change.  I just added the following to the `gst_tcp_client_sink_start()` function of gsttcpclientsink.c:

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 60;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
...
setsockopt (this->sock_fd.fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

The strange thing is that the actual timeout (measured by wall clock time) is always double the value I set.  If I disrupt the network connection with the timeout set to 60 seconds, it will take 120 seconds for GStreamer/socket to abort.  If I set the timeout to 30 seconds, it will take 60 seconds.  If I set the timeout to 180 seconds, it will take 360 seconds.  Is there something about sockets that I don't understand that might be causing this behavior?  I'd really like to know what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a duplicate of [Socket SO_RCVTIMEO Timeout is double the set value in C++/VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298040/socket-so-rcvtimeo-timeout-is-double-the-set-value-in-c-vc)

I'm pasting my answer below since I think I had a similar problem.

## Pasted answer

SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO do not work on all socket operations, you should use non-blocking mode and `select`.

The behaviour may change on different operating system configurations.
On my system the `connect` timeouts after two times the value I set in SO_RCVTIMEO. A quick hack like setting SO_RCVTIMEO to `x/2` before a connect and `x` after it works, but the proper solution is using select.

## References

Discussion on this problem (read comments to answer):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182564/4074995

How to use select to achive the desired result:

- http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select
- [C: socket connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597608/c-socket-connection-timeout)