# Socket SO_RCVTIMEO Timeout is double the set value in C++/VC++

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++

Please, show below example

```
int val = 120000;
setsockopt(connSock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,(char*)&val,sizeof(int));
```

I set 120 seconds at receive timeout but it takes 240 seconds.

I think timeout is double the set value.

how is it possible?

Comment: Did you check to make sure `setsockopt()` is not returning an error? What code are you expecting the timeout to apply to? Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that shows the double-time in action.

Answer (score 2):

`SO_RCVTIMEO` does not accept an `int` as the timeout.  You're looking for something like this:

```
struct timeval tv = {
    .tv_sec = 120
};

setsockopt(connSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv));
```

Answer (score 1):

SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO do not work on all socket operations, you should use non-blocking mode and `select`.

The behaviour may change on different operating system configurations.
On my system the `connect` timeouts after two times the value I set in SO_RCVTIMEO. A quick hack like setting SO_RCVTIMEO to `x/2` before a connect and `x` after it works, but the proper solution is using select.

## References

Discussion on this problem (read comments to answer):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182564/4074995

How to use select to achive the desired result:

- http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select
- [C: socket connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597608/c-socket-connection-timeout)